# automatic field update when GET object is called. is it right and possible? drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is the best way to implement the next situation:
I need that when some object endpoint is GET called then `isCalled` change to True.
for example when `api/objects/1`

my model:

```
class Object (models.Model):
    someObject = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    isCalled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # dateCalled = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

my views.py:

```
class SingleMessageView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    # def get(self)? : #function to implement the solution should be here?
```

is it possible? what is the most efficient way to implement it and where (views.py/ serializers.py) to put the solution? THANKS!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`retrieve()`** method

```
from rest_framework.response import Response


class SingleMessageView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.isCalled = True
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i have done it, but its not working. I would like it to change it when calling GET method (is it posiible?)

Comment: oops..my mistake. I have updated the answer. Check it

Comment: checked, now it saying that Response is not defined. from where should i import it? im creating only REST api without any front (with rest-framework)

Comment: Have you not seen that in the answer? I have already added it

Comment: wow.. sorry, this is what happend after hours of sitting on the computer. and its worked man! THANKS ALOTTT!!!!